# Roles of the vocal cords

Tags: phonetics, articulation

I've heard that there are 3 parts to the vocal cords: the true vocal cords, and the "false" vestibular folds and ventricular ligament. I read that the vestibular serves some function in chanting and such but was not clear what purpose the ventricular is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood your informational source. The terms *vestibular folds* and *ventricular folds* respectively refer to the same anatomical structures. They are synonyms. See [the Wikipedia article on vestibular folds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibular_fold).